# angular: how to provide an alternative web-site for older browsers

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, legacy

I'm developing a responsive web app using mobile-angular-ui.

In older browsers (IE8, IE7, etc) many things don't work.

I was thinking about providing an alternative web site with plain twitter bootstrap, but I'd like to reuse as much javascript as possible. Ideally I'd like to just use a set of different templates, and keep my services and controllers.

How could I achieve it?

Comment: Are you sure it's really what you want to do? Do you know how many users will be on these. IE8 usage is continuing to drop. If it's such a low percentage it's not worth supporting. Especially IE7. For instance my work website only has 2.5% on IE8 and we are dropping support for it.

Comment: Yes, it's going to be used in an organization where many users have IE8 and IE9, that's all I need (no IE7 nor IE6 support)

Comment: IE9 is fine as the latest version supports it. IE8 is the issue as it's not supported by the Angular team. Would it be possible to get the organisation to either install a separate browser for your app or upgrade to a newer IE. I have had success in the past in doing this. Otherwise you are kind of stuck and it's going to be difficult to maintain with two different versions of the app.

Comment: You may have some success with using these builds: https://github.com/fergaldoyle/angular.js-ie8-builds

Comment: angular 1.2 just works in ie8

Comment: I thought it would be a rather common scenario, having a legacy version of the site and trying to share as much code as possible. besides the site itself is rather simple: http://mteyss.github.io/concursos

Comment: Use enterprise Mode to smoth your companys migration away from XP to Win7/8/10
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/04/02/stay-up-to-date-with-enterprise-mode-for-internet-explorer-11.aspx]